# How to implement comment system with only 1 depth level

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments, hierarchy

I've read that the best solution for comment system is [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

However, I plan to allow replies only for the top comments - only one depth level. In this case, the structure become much more simpler than a complicated tree.

Is there any other way to implement it in this scenario? Something easier, simpler, quicker?

Answer (score 2):

A implementation for 1 level is the same as a implementations for N levels.

The only difference is that you only use 1 level.

A possible implementation looks like this: put all the comments in 1 table, and use a foreign key to the blog article or whatever you commenting on. The nesting is stored in the ParentCommentId. Id its NULL it is a root comment, if it has a value if is a comment on a other comment.

It is very easy then to make a simple comment form and store the results in the database.

The table structure could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Comments` (
  `CommentId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BlogId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentCommentId` int(11),
  `Content` text NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EMail` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Url` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CommentId`),
  KEY `FK_Blog` (`BlogId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CommentBlog` FOREIGN KEY (`BlogId`) REFERENCES `Blogs` (`BlogId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough ;) I want to know how should I implement a REPLAY feature. Example: There are comments A,B,C,D where A and C are top comments and B & D are replays for comment A

Comment: Ahh .. sorry to misread your posting. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Your solution makes it very hard to read from database

Comment: reading would be very easy: `select * from comments where BlogId=:BlogId and ParentCommentId is Null` to get all the top level comments. When folding out in the client, the nested comments can be read.

Comment: @GuryMax you mean `reply` and not `replay`

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to get the top comments - I want to get first comment, answers to first comment, second comment...